Rubocop rule for separated keyword arguments in ruby 3
I'm making a slowly upgrade on a huge rails app with rails 5 and ruby 2.7, to rails 7 and ruby 3. I want to add a rubocop rule that warns users of deprecated stuff in ruby 3 while still using ruby 2.7, to prevent further PRs of deprecated stuff.
My rubocop configuration has TargetRubyVersion: 3.0 for AllCops, and it does catch some stuff, but not all. At this time, I'm trying to decide how to deal with the new separated keyword arguments in ruby 3 as shown here.
Basically methods like this one def old_style(name, options = {}) should be warned about in favor of def new_style(name, **options).
Is there maybe a cop that I havent tried, or an external plugin that will check this for me? I'm using Rubocop 0.92.0 at the moment.

There is nothing wrong with your old_style method. That style of method declaration is not deprecated.

@user229044 is correct that that style is not deprecated. However, if you still want to discourage option hashes as a matter of project style, you can use the OptionHash cop: https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.63/cops_style.html#styleoptionhash

You guys are right, what ruby 3 actually shows errors for is when you have def new_style(**args), but then make a call to that method like new_style(my_hash) or new_style({ age: 10 }), instead of new_style(**my_hash). Can I detect these with Rubocop?

I might be wrong here but Rubocop does purely static analysis so it doesn't actually know the signature of the target method. Hopefully your tests would catch that though.
